# Reference for the p-adic numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, p-adic-number-theory

> Can anyone give me a reference (book or a paper) that introduces the p-adic numbers and their important properties? Also, I would love if that reference contained some not to advanced applications of the p-adic numbers to number theory.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

p-adic Numbers, p-adic Analysis, and Zeta-Functions, Neal Koblitz (1984, ISBN 978-0-387-96017-3)

This is a short book. If you wish, you can only read the first chapter with 20 pages.

Comment: +1. Koblitz book is a better choice than Gouvea's, because it's number theory-oriented, while the "p-adic numbers: an introduction" focuses on analysis in $\mathbb Q_p$ and the construction of $\mathbb C_p$.

Answer (score 3):

The book by Fernando Gouvea called 'p-adic numbers: an introduction' is quite nice elementary book for p-adic numbers.

Comment: This is the one I recommend most strongly.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above, which are good, try  Baker's notes  on p-adic numbers and  Schikhof's Ultrametric Calculus (Cambridge Univ. Press). I ve got both free over the net.